# How to push a commit using git cherry-pick with a different commit comment

Tags: git, github, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I have used git cherry-pick to push a commit from branch a to branch b .

git checkout branch b

git cherry-pick commit-hash

Which worked fine but I couldn't find a way to update the push comment. Whatever comment was provided earlier for branch a same is reflecting for branch b as well. Is there a way I can modify push comment before actually pushing the commit to my origin branch?

Comment: As in the answers below, you can amend or use `-n`, but the shortest command is `git cherry-pick -e <commit-specifier>`. The `-e` option is short for `--edit` (you can spell it out if you like); that tells Git to open the editor on the prepared commit message.

Comment: @torek I read that in the docs. When I tried it I got `fatal: bad revision <new commit message>`

Comment: @user1007074: A "commit specifier" is what you find listed in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions). Commit *messages* are not commit specifiers unless you use them with some additional searching syntax. Typically though you'd run `git log` to find the commit of interest, then use your mouse to cut out the *hash ID*, and paste that in to your `git cherry-pick` command.

Answer (score 4):

Beside `git commit --amend`, you can also use `git cherry-pick <commit-hash> -n && git commit`. `-n` instructs `git cherry-pick` to apply the changes only and not to create the commit. You can specify the commit message in the subsequent `git commit`.

Comment: `-n` is short for `--no-commit`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly : you want to edit the message of the commit you just cherry-picked before pushing the whole branch to github.

You can do this using :

```
git commit --amend
```

from the command line, or look for an `amend` checkbox in the GUI you are using for git.